# How to highlight the first cell in a column that matches criteria with conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

In one column of a spreadsheet I want to highlight the first cell ONLY above a specific number. For example, if a column has values increasing from 0 in the first row to x in the last row, how do I highlight the first cell ONLY in that column that is greater than a certain value. It can't be a specific cell either because the spreadsheet is formulated to change the values in each row based on previous rows.

Basically I want Excel to identify and highlight the first cell ONLY in a column greater than or equal to a certain value regardless of how many rows are being used.

Answer (score 1):

`=countif()` will allow you to build a conditional formatting formula that lets you check to see when the count of the number of cells from the top of the column through the current column is equal to 1.

For example:

```
=COUNTIF($I$7:I7,">="&$K$7)=1
```

Where the cells to check are in column `I` starting with row `7` and the conditional value is stored in `$K$7` The `$I$7:I7` reference will keep `$I$7` as the start and continue through `I7` which can change to `I8` and so on as the formula is applied lower in the column.

For you situation in the comment the following should work:

```
=COUNTIF($F$2:F2,">=1000000")=1
```

Note that the comparison now is included directly inside the formula instead of referencing an external cell and that the addresses have been changed to handle column `F`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm not familiar with Excel very much. Let me explain exactly what I want and hopefully you can give me the correct formula. I have a spreadsheet where in column F the F2 value is the first value and is $0, the last value is F50 and is $9,000,000. How can I get the column to highlight the first cell ONLY greater than or equal to $1,000,000?